# Ubuntu VirtualBox guest not showing wireless extensions in iwconfig 

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on my Mac using Oracle VirtualBox. My machine is connected to Wi-Fi and am able to browse the internet from within Ubuntu as well. However, `iwconfig` does not give an option for wlan0.

Could someone help me out? What am I doing wrong here?

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

The output of lspci is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 
                                                                                       02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev  
                                                                                      01)
00:06.0 USB Controller: Apple Computer Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI   
                                                                    Controller (rev 02)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual guest does not see the wifi interface in your host machine.  Instead, it sees a virtual NIC presented by VirtualBox.